SIS decision letter interpretation
I made an inquiry in the Finnish SIS to see if there are any alerts on me in the SIS database and I received a very ambiguous response hopefully someone here can help me interpret
It says

National police board states that no information about you in the Finnish SIS for which you could use your right of access. This does not exclude the possibility that there is an alert issued by another country.

Can you please tell me is that no information or there is something?

I don't think you can know for sure. Note that there are some categories of data which they can store in the SIS but not disclose to you anyway. Is there any reason you think there is data about you stored in the SIS, and if so, which country would have added it there?

https://home-affairs.ec.europa.eu/policies/schengen-borders-and-visa/schengen-information-system/access-rights-and-data-protection_en  Also the other pages refers to who has access (and for what reason). I think Finnish SIS cannot access information of other countries to share to you (or other scope outside permission), so you must ask each countries

@GiacomoCatenazzi If you look at the "comprehensive guide" linked at the bottom, you'll see that in the procedures of many other countries they explicitly state that they will share info from other countries only with approval of said countries. So they can do it (no idea if they all do it). But there are many cases when they just won't tell you (even for national data).

Hopefully my answer will help you interpret the answer yourself but otherwise it would depend a bit on the circumstances: Any specific reason to ask Finland? What are you most concerned about (past criminal investigation, immigration infringement, family issues)?

@jcaron there is no reason to think that at all. I applied for a schengen visa through Finland in 2017 and got rejected and I worry that they found my docs suspicious or something that thry placed a SIS ban on me so I sent an inquiry to check

@Fgs What was the justification for the refusal?

@jcaron but from the same letter doesnt the phrase saying this doesnt exclude the possibility of alerts about you in other schengen states indicate that this decision does exclude alerts about me in the Finnish SIS? English wise I feel like this is what it says

@Relaxed cant remember at all was long time ago but I panicked about the SIS thing very recently when I read about it so decided to do the inquiry

@Relaxed from your thorough response I would assume if hypothetically the Finnish consulate saw that I provided false documents (which I promise never happened) all I did was provide a flight reservation when a ticket was needed and made a small mistake in the entry where it asks First country of entry. This sort of alert would fall under entry ban right? Which would be disclosed in this response. I never went to the schengen region so no criminal or any other reason for the alerts to exist right?

@Fgs if you had been banned for this they would have told you. Also I believe such information is more likely to be in the VIS rather than the SIS, and should have now expired.

@jcaron thank you for that yes VIS for the refusal but SIS for the entry ban if they suspected false documents but I guess this falls under entry ban alerts and not something major like public safety. Its worth saying that was my first and last encounter with the Schengen region this visa application to Finland. Never been since then and never even applied again since then. Dont know if that strengthens my situation

@Fgs I am not sure why you think there was a concern about the authenticity of the documents you submitted but if the Finnish consulate was concerned about that, the main tool they have would be a ban. You should have been notified of it and there is no reason it would not be disclose following your request for any SIS alert about you. It would also be mentioned in any visa refusal if you apply now. The reason for the refusal would, however, be recorded in the VIS.

@Relaxed absolutely no reason i just panicked when i saw Germany putting these non authentic documents bans on people who provide flights itinerary and not a ticket and I went into overthinking (i always overthink) and thought Finland might have done that when I did the same thing in 2017 and therefore inquired about SIS. And thanks for pointing out the situation clearly yes its only the consulate that I dealt with and I guess even if it existed in the first place its probably expired by now it has been 7 years

@jcaron Entry bans are not limited to people who need a visa and go in the SIS (article 24, alert for the purpose of refusing entry), not in the VIS. The VIS only records information about past applications (including refusals and the reasons behind it) and nothing else.

@Relaxed I inquired about VIS and was told the record was removed as it cleans every five years

@Fgs This is getting a little complicated for comments, if you want more details on the VIS and what happens when a consulate suspects you submitted false documents, I would suggest asking another question.

@Relaxed thank you will do

This simply means that there's no information they're going to give you. There may or may not be information they aren't going to give you, information related to law enforcement and exempt from subject access rights.
Obviously they couldn't tell everyone either "there's no information, period" or "there's no information we're willing to give you", because the latter would effectively inform the person that there's something. So this response doesn't specifically indicate that there's information they're not willing to give you. It's boilerplate.

There is a bit of a contradiction between privacy laws and law enforcement. The EU likes to think of itself as exemplary when it comes to data protection but law enforcement agencies always seek exemptions from these rules and regulations. Making a file or database easy to probe by the public can also make national agencies more reluctant to share data. The way it has been resolved in the Schengen acquis is by creating this right of access (that does not always exist as such for national police files) but with several safeguards and no obligation for national authorities to be fully transparent.
Under the law, national contact points may therefore restrict access for the following reasons:

The right to access your data can be denied in certain circumstances. The right of access can be restricted when such a restriction, considering your rights, is necessary and proportionate to safeguard

the prevention, investigation, detection or prosecution of criminal offences or the execution of criminal penalties,
another official investigation, audit or other such procedure,
public security,
national security, or
the protection of the rights of others.


In theory, they have to provide a justification when they deny the right of access but they can also avoid that if they deem that providing the justification would also jeopardize an investigation, national security etc. etc. etc. (which could easily be extended to all cases where denying access is justified in the first place). That's the reason behind the deliberately vague answer you received.
Unless they abuse the law to basically thwart any request from the public, it would however imply that the Finnish authorities have not imposed a run-of-the-mill alert for the purpose of denying entry (article 24 decision, i.e. ban), i.e. the kind of bans for which you would get some sort of paper and an opportunity to appeal. I am guessing it would also rule out an alert under article 32 (missing persons). There could still be a ban for some sensitive political reason or based on intelligence that the authorities do not want to disclose or maybe another type of alert (arrest, covert surveillance, assistance with a judicial procedure…) as it's easy to see why those should be kept secret.
There is also a bit of leeway on how to deal with alerts issued by other countries. The Finnish national police board has access to those and “may” provide information on them to you after informing the issuing state (article 67 of the regulation) but it's not entirely clear whether they positively have to bother seeking this permission or they can just ignore these alerts.
For context, bans are the most common type of alerts about persons, 56% in 2022. Alerts based on article 36 of the SIS II regulation (discreet or specific checks) are the second most common type after bans.

Thank you for your detailed comment. Answering your top comment too I am jot worried about criminal or immigration infringement or any of that I just applied for a visa in 2017 and worried that my documents were suspicious to them and they placed an alert on me maybe I am overthinking but thats my situation
